# What are valid characters in an X11 .conf Identifier name?

Tags: x11, configuration

Where can I find what characters are valid in an X11 config file `Identifier` name?

I'd like to name my identifier `libinput touchpad disable tap-to-click` but I don't know if hyphens are valid.

I'm running Manjaro Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think there are any particular restrictions, apart from the use of quotes; [the configuration file manpage](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml) doesn’t mention anything specific. Looking at [the parser source code](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/tree/hw/xfree86/parser/scan.c#n386), a string can contain anything apart from double quotes, carriage returns, newlines and the null byte.

You should certainly be able to use hyphens.